# Downgrading .NET Framework causing packages issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on a project on TFS. This project was created on someone else's PC on VS 2017 and the newest .NET framework and published to Azure.

I got the project on my PC, I have VS 2015 and I had to change the .NET framework of the project to 4.6. Everything was fine, I could make changes to the project and commit.

But when I tried to publish to Azure from my PC, I got a very unclear error:

```
Publish Failed
Connecting to ...
```

Looking for solutions online, I had to downgrade the version of the package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` from `2.6.1` to `2.4.0` . And that worked !

I turned off my PC. Next day when I opened the project and ran it, I got this error locally :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.6.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried to uninstall `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and reinstall it with version `2.6.1` , but it says i need `a newer version of nuget`.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I already installed all the updates in my **Tools** -> **Extensions** -> **Updates** but nothing changed.

Why are all these things happening to my project and how can i fix it?

PS: upgrading my VS to 2017 is currently not an option due to many exterior reasons.
Thank you.

Comment: Does it specifically mention what version of nuget it wants?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no it just says newer

Comment: why downgrade everything? Why not just install newer .net framework?

Comment: Best solution would be to install VS2017 as well. You can install both versions in parallel. If you don't use ApplicationInsights you could simply remove the project reference completely. I believe VS likes to add it automatically to promote the feature.

Comment: @Greg I have plenty of other projects who run on VS2015 and don't have the hardware to support having both versions.

Comment: These are likely mishaps when you have an old version of VS and Nuget.  These packages change quite rapidly and often assume you have the latest updates.  Intentionally picking an older version of the package is a workaround.  Team members ought to agree on the VS version they use to limit this kind of headache.  Hardware can't be a problem, it is an opportunity to get new shiny metal.  Go get it now.

Comment: @HansPassant you make some very good points. But sadly the situation I'm in has no proper team organization (we've all been through that) - and I am not able to upgrade my hardwara ATM. That's why I was hoping someone would suggest a workaround until the situation changes.

Comment: One workaround would be to create a new project solution, as {projectname}_2015.sln or something, and to configure it for your environment. Then add the .csproj files from the VS2017 solution.

Comment: @Greg removing all the packages related to `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and deleting `ApplicationInsights.config` did the trick. thank you. is there no side effect whatsoever to this?

Comment: Well you can't use [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) anymore :D Its a monitoring tool that runs on Azure, and so is pushed by Microsoft. But the app will run fine without it.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT well deleting the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and  `ApplicationInsights.config` files made it work again. But i'm hesitant to publish to Azure without this package fearing that it might create conflict.

Comment: @Greg hey, sorry for the recurring questions, so if i got you right removing applicationInsight on my project locally and then **publishing** it to Azure without this package wont stop the website from running?

Comment: I wasn't sure, so I just created a new ASP.NET Core 2 app and published it to Azure. I manually removed Application Insights and after re-publishing got a 500 message. Turns out Insights adds quite a few references including a JavaScript call in the views. After removing that everything worked again. So just be sure you've removed all Application Insights references and it should work.

Comment: @Greg can you be more specific about the references? Are they the ones in packages.config? What about the Javascript code? Any guidance on how to locate everything? Thanks a bunch

Comment: I searched the whole solution (ctrl+shift+f) for `Insights`. Depending on your solution you will find references to the library in multiple configuration files. I overlooked an JavaScript entry in one of my views. To be safe you could create a second project on Azure and deploy it there first.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten that error locally as well and was actually able to resolve by manually adding the file to my project folder, may be worth a shot.

Comment: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` file?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Yes, just pasting the package itself within your VS project folder. If this doesn't work I would also try removing your temporary files (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files) and readding them manually in that folder. I've literally managed to fix this error by simply rebooting Visual Studio as well so it's quite unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

> Downgrading .NET Framework causing packages issues

Just like Hans said nuget packages change quite rapidly, which often require the latest version NuGet. Some new features in the package only supported by the newer NuGet (like PackageReference) or some issues fixed on the newer version. For example, install package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1` on Visual Studio 2015, which requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above.

So, the workaround for this issue is create a new project with Visual Studio 2015,  copy the code from previous projects, then add those nuget package one by one to find out the reason why it needs the newer version nuget.

**However,** I want to talk more over about this question is that **the best way to resolve this issue is to install Visual Studio 2017 alongside Visual Studio 2015**. As we known, using a lower version of the Visual Studio and .net framework to open a higher version of the Visual Studio and .net framework is not recommended, it will always bring a lot of incompatibility errors and some other weird issues. Since upgrade your Visual Studio to 2017 is currently not an option due to many exterior reasons, so I suggest that you can install Visual Studio 2017 alongside Visual Studio 2015. Besides, developing the same project with different versions of Visual Studio and submitting it to the TFS server may bring many unpredictable risks.

Hope this helps.